# Alert not executing when redirected from other page

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code in the body tag of a view in MVC. The problem is that the alert message is displayed on first time loading of the page but it isn't executing when the control is coming through redirect.

Also, I have used the break point to see that the code is executing but it doesn't execute the alert line.

@{

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    @if (TempData["notice"] != null)
    {
        @:alert(TempData["notice"]);
    }
    else 
    {
        @:alert("No notice");          
    }
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if you want to use tamp data value in javascript use this syntax
>
> '@TempData["notice"]'

```
@{  
<script type="text/javascript">
    @if (TempData["notice"] != null)
    {
        @:alert('@TempData["notice"]');
    }
    else 
    {
        @:alert('@TempData["no notice"]');          
          }
</script>
    }
```

Comment: After applying this change as suggested by @zohaib  Now the break-point is coming at the alert line (after redirect) but it is still not displaying the alert message pop up on the website.

Comment: I have removed Debugger and now copy paste this code
and make sure tempdata value is set before redirecting